# Getting same rich text format twice is not equal

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, clipboard, equality

I have tried the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Copy clipboard text twice
    TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
    TextBox2.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)

    If TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text Then
        'this is the output while copying from Notepad
        OutputTextBox.Text = "True"

    Else
        'this is the output while copying from MS Word
        OutputTextBox.Text = "False"
    End If

End Sub
```

When I copy text from MS Word, getting rich text format twice is not same. Though the text has been copied once and assigned twice.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.

When getting clipboard contents from Word the data is retrieved from the running instance of Word. (Close Word you'll see the clipboard is empty.) When the data is retrieved Word bumps a RSID (Revision Save IDs) for some reason.

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/46805.html Oldde But Goodie in this case.

FYI WinMerge is a fine GUI comparison tool for files. NotePad++ has a nice compare add-in.

Here are the differences in two calls:
{*\rsidtbl \rsid4800747\rsid12415067}
{*\rsidtbl \rsid4800747\rsid13042328}

Comment: Thank you! I have found the difference between TextBox1.Text and TextBox2.Text in the nearly ending parts.